# UIScrollView Notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, notifications

Is there any notification sent when `UIScrollView` changes its scroll state? I would like to listen to that notification rather than using delegate methods.

Comment: what's is the problem with delegate methods???

Comment: I think the point is that notifications can be use globally rather than delegate methods which can pass information to one object only: the delegate. If the value needs to be observed by many objects it is better to use notifications or KVO. But be aware: these ways are heavy and may impact performance significantly

Comment: Due to some reasons , i am not able to use delegate methods? It will be very easy for me if there is any notification that i can listen to get scroll view state change...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use delegate methods you can observe contentOffset value changes using KVO (key-value-observing)

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `UIScrollView`, overload `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, and send this notification every time your scroll view will scroll.
As the scrolls need to be lightweight events I would not recommend using notifications for every scroll as it will impact your performance much greater than using a delegate method.

Answer (score -1):

These are the delegates that handle scrolling for `UIScrollView`.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

Is there any specific reason you dont prefer delegates & want notifications? So you can use `scrollViewDidScroll` for any changes in scroll state.